# Animate SVG waves with greensock library

Tags: javascript, svg, paperjs, gsap

I'm trying to create a wave effect with [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap) library and SVG. [This example](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) shows what I would like to do. Unfortunately that code is built on top of the Paper.js library.

I understand that the wave is composed of N segments that are animated on every call of the onFrame function (called in turn by requestAnimationFrame). The first part of the code (correct me if I'm wrong) just generates a bunch of segments that composes a long line (and this can be done in SVG too with a set of aligned path/line elements). In [TweenMax](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/) I found that there is an `onUpdate` event that's called every frame of an animation, however I don't understand how I could use it to animate the fragments of the SVG.

The question is simple: can this code be ported to GSAP with SVG instead of canvas and how?

Comment: Have you seen GSAP's [DrawSVGPlugin](http://greensock.com/drawSVG)? May prove to be very useful.

Comment: The plugin is a commercial feature, I'm searching something free. It seems really cool but I don't think it could help me because I don't want to progressively reveal the wave, I just want it to animate like a sine wave

Comment: True. I suggest to come up with a basic SVG and try animating it by yourself first. If you get stuck somewhere, I will be happy to help you out if I can.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that I don't know how I could animate with GSAP the SVG waves frame-by-frame (what Paper.js is doing in the example) rather than using a predefined animation

Comment: There could be multiple solutions to that. You could use exactly the same frame-by-frame animation approach by utilising [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) API. This way, you won't even need to use `TweenMax` or any other tweening library at all. But this approach will probably be very difficult to manage. Or, read through [this massive article](http://greensock.com/svg-tips) on GSAP website to fully understand how you could do that using `TweenMax` containing examples and inspiration.

Comment: I think the only way to do frame-by-frame animation in realtime is by using myself requestAnimationFrame. I will try that, mybe using TweenMax.set method to set the attributes and see if that works

Comment: Not identical animation but similar concept. Move mouse in and out of result area: http://jsfiddle.net/alkhoo/JwkYm/11/